# How to properly escape a translated string?

Tags: escaping

I'm having trouble understanding how to escape a translated string with WordPress...

The following piece of code is from the Wordpress codex :

```
function wpdocs_kantbtrue_init()
{
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Recipes', 'Post type general name', 'recipe' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Recipe', 'Post type singular name', 'recipe' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Recipes', 'Admin Menu text', 'recipe' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Recipe', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'recipe' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'recipe' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New recipe', 'recipe' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New recipe', 'recipe' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit recipe', 'recipe' ),

            ... 
        )
    );

    register_post_type('Recipe', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'wpdocs_kantbtrue_init');
```

I think I read somewhere that everything should be escaped and I am pretty sure that the __() function does not escape anything, it just returns the translated text...

I have also seen this somewhere :

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('address', array(
    'default'           =>  esc_html__('Enter your Address in this field', 'themename'),
    'sanitize_callback' =>  'sanitize_text_field',
    'transport'         =>  'postMessage'
));
```

So what's the safest way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a baked in solution:

`esc_html__( string $text, string $domain = 'default' )`

You can use that to replace `__()` and `__x()` but the second one looks for contextual translations where you specify the context for the string being translated.

The codex for it is right here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/